# Unable to delete primordial storage pool from Win 10 storage spaces

Tags: windows, storage-spaces

I have Windows 10 Pro with one storage pool (2 way mirror out of 4 disks)
when I run `get-storagepool` command I see there is another strange storage pool `Primordial` which I did not create.

```
FriendlyName  OperationalStatus HealthStatus IsPrimordial IsReadOnly    Size AllocatedSize
------------  ----------------- ------------ ------------ ----------    ---- -------------
Primordial    OK                Healthy      True         False      4.76 TB        3.6 TB
Storage pool1 OK                Healthy      False        False       3.6 TB       1.86 TB
```

When I try to delete this pool, I get the error and 0 google results on it.

```
Remove-StoragePool -FriendlyName Primordial
```

```
WARNING: An operation was attempted on the primordial storage pool
which was not supported. This operation might have succeeded for other
objects in the pipeline.
Remove-StoragePool : This operation is not supported on primordial storage pools.
Activity ID: {d02ca163-e71d-4d67-9a69-705b736f5c69}
At line:1 char:1
 1. Remove-StoragePool -FriendlyName Primordial
 2. ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (StorageWMI:ROOT/Microsoft/...SFT_StoragePool) [Remove-StoragePool], C
   imException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StorageWMI 48000,Remove-StoragePool
```

1. What does it mean "not supported"
2. How to delete this storage pool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primordial is the default storage pool for any unprovisioned disks.  It’s like pergatory for your disks before you either create a pool out of them, add them to a pool or format them as a standalone drive.

There is one primordial per storage subsystem.

I think you can effectively make the pool at least go empty by doing something like “set-disk -canpool:False”. IIRC